# vim-pathogen is ignoring 'after' directory

Tags: vim, pathogen

I am using this [plugin](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) which only ships with 'after' directory, containing 'plugin' and 'syntax'  directories.

[Here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/blob/master/autoload/pathogen.vim#L118), it looks like the 'after' directory is added to run time path as well.

If I manually move the 'plugin' and 'syntax' directories to the bundles/indentLine root the plugin works, the commands are recognized.

Any suggestions on what's going wrong? How do I debug? How do I add print statements in there?

EDIT: I am going to clarify this a little more.

I have a directory layout ~/.vim/bundles. All of my plugins that are from gitrepos are here, so you are looking at something like -

Output:

```
~/.vim/bundle
|-- nerdtree
|   |-- syntax
|   `-- plugin
|-- indentLine
|   `-- after
|       `-- syntax
|       `-- plugin
`-- vim-surround
    |-- syntax
    `-- plugin
```

scriptnames includes nerdtree and vim-surround. However, indentLine doesn't show up in scriptnames. If I move the "syntax" and "plugin" directories from "indentLine\after" into the "indentLine" directory, then indentLine shows up in `:scriptnames` as well.

Basically, the `:indentLines\after` directory is not looked into for plugins.

Comment: That plugin works as advertised, here. Do you see `indentline` in the output of `:scriptnames`?

Comment: :IndentLinesToggle <-- This returns no such command .

Comment: How did you install it? Where? Do you see it in `:scriptnames`?

Comment: I put it in the 'bundle' directory as usual, with the rest of my plugins. When I print my `set runtimepath`, it includes the indentLines directory. However, `scriptnames` does *not* include indentLines

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer in Vim docs. When running `:help runtime` a list of directories comes up that are searched for vim scripts. The `after` directory is not one of them. A full list can be found [here](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27).

So when Pathogen adds your `bundle` directories to runtimepath, it doesn't actually add the `after` directories.

So what can we do? Well, you can manually add your after script to the runtimepath. So you can create a `.vim/bundle/indentLine/plugin/setup.vim` script with the following contents:

```
set runtimepath.="," . expand("<sfile>:h:p") . "/../after/"
```

That way your `after` directory is added to the end of the runtimepath and actually processed